# can I decouple facebook access from my symfony2 app through a node.js app?

Tags: php, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I have a symfony2 frontend application and I'd like to delegate all the asynchronous comunication with facebook through a node.js wrapper API, so if facebook change things I have to work on the nodejs API only. Is it possible? Can I let the user authorize the app and grant permissions starting from the frontend app and then let the node.js app wrap all the communications with the facebook API for the frontend app?

Comment: How would you get the data into nodejs and have it use that data continuously? Just curious. Sf2 + Fb + Nodejs sounds like Fuuuun.

Comment: Well I don't have real time needs, I'm developing of a couple of ways to do it, one of which is a memcached request/response queue, or something similar. But it's just ideas, I'm at the very beginning :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You just pass the access token you obtain for each Facebook user to the node.js wrapper API.